# Why does validates_uniqueness_of run before before_create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my invite.rb model I have the following:

```
class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :assign_code
  validates_uniqueness_of :code, :case_sensitive => false, :message => "This invite code is taken!"

  protected

  # Create a safe random token and ensuring it's uniqueness for the model
  def assign_code
    begin
      code = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while Invite.where(:code => code).exists?
    self.code = code
  end
```

Problem is in the logs I see the follow below. Why is rails doing a query for a code which is null, seems like a wasted query.

```
Invite Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "invites" WHERE "invites"."code" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Invite Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "invites" WHERE "invites"."code" = 'mTGCX0yCyTgplGfGQ5hGeA' LIMIT 1
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `before_validation :assign_code` instead, that way the code gets set before it's validated.

Answer (score 1):

The first query is from the validation callback (before the code is set) and checks that no other `Invite` has an empty `code`. The second is from the `Invite.where(:code => code).exists?`.

The order of the callbacks is shown [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). So I think you should call `assign_code` as a `before_validation` callback instead of `before_create`. And then you might be able to skip the check yourself that the `code` is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing an AccessToken class for my RESTful API, I got the same problem with validates_presence_of and the before_creation callbacks order.
As suggested above, I used before_validation instead of _create but it gave me a new problem: my method was called at every update, changing my token key and then out-dated the data hold by users' devices.
Solved that by checking if it was a new record or not:
`self.token = SecureRandom.hex if new_record?`